# Create FTP mount using GIO library

Tags: c, gio

I'm trying to use [GIO](http://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/). I figured out how to use GVolumeMonitor to catch volume changes and get list of volumes. `g_volume_monitor_get_mounts` function gives me a list of existing GMount's. Each of them can represent a HDD partition or a mount of network share (ftp, smb, sftp etc). Mounting a HDD partition seems to be possible using `g_volume_mount`. But how to create GMount representing a network share? Which classes are responsible for this?

Here is my code:

```
GVolumeMonitor* monitor = g_volume_monitor_get();
GList* list = g_volume_monitor_get_mounts(monitor);
for(; list; list = list->next) {
  GMount* mount = static_cast<GMount*>(list->data);
  GFile* file = g_mount_get_root(mount);
  qDebug() << "Mount(" << g_mount_get_name(mount) << 
              ", " << g_file_get_path(file) << ")";
}
```

(I know there must be `g_object_unref` and `g_list_free`.)

Output:

```
Mount( SFTP for ri on host.org ,  /home/ri/.gvfs/SFTP for ri on host.org ) 
Mount( Yellow hard disk ,  /media/Yellow hard disk )
```

I was created the first sftp mount using nautilus. Now I want to implement this functionality myself. Target OS is Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be looking for [`g_file_mount_enclosing_volume()`](http://developer.gnome.org/gio/2.32/GFile.html#g-file-mount-enclosing-volume)